# Commands will not pass to CLI after logging into new user with sudo su - user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scripting

Obligatory 'first post' tag. **Issue:** Commands will not pass to command line after entering password for a `sudo su - userB`

I am writing a script in bash that requires to be run as a specific user. Ideally we would like this script to be able to be run on our local workstations for ease of use. Here is the command I am running to test:

```
ssh -qt -p22 userA@hostname "whoami; sudo su - userB; whoami"

Expected:
userA
[sudo] password for userA:
userB
```

With this command I am able to get the prompt for sudo password but once it is entered I am presented with a normal terminal where I can manually run commands. Once I ctrl-D/exit it runs the second whoami as the userA and closes. I work in an extremely jailed environment so sudo su -c and similar "run-as-root" commands do not work and I cannot ssh directly to userB.

Is there any way to send the commands to userB by logging in with `sudo su - userB`?

Comment: There is actually no "obligatory first post tag", quite the opposite really ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`su` creates a subshell that reads the commands from standard input by default. It executes `whoami` after that exits. You can use the `-c` option to pass a command to it.

```
ssh -qt -p22 userA@hostname "whoami; sudo su - userB -c 'whoami'"
```

You can also use the `-u` option to `sudo` instead of using `su`:

```
ssh -qt -p22 userA@hostname "whoami; sudo -u userB whoami"
```

Comment: The first option presented looks to still try to run as 'root'. The second option is closer but I am thinking that the environment is just too jailed to run the script as desired. We will likely need to work with getting new permissions or access. Thanks for the information otherwise

Comment: I just tried the first version and it worked correctly. I accidentally had `-u` there before, try it now.

Comment: Still no luck at the moment. Running as root will not work on this system:

`Sorry, user userA is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/su - userB -c whoami' as root on host.`

Comment: Very strange that they allow userA to run `su`, which allows it to run any command, but don't allow it to run commands directly.

Comment: They have heavy security policies layered in weird ways from what I have seen. Not a fan, but gotta make due. I will have to figure out some other way in or method to gather the data we need.