# ssh from server A to B and run as sudo su then su - grid

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, scripting, cron

All my servers are redhat linux 8.

I am trying to run a script from serverA to serverB and run commands: then run it from crontab

This is what I do manually:
on serverA as root with my key.pem in /home:
ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No -i "Key.pem" user@BserverB
sudo su -
su - grid.  (this is for oracle)
crsctl stop has
su -
shutdown now

I have tried this below command in my script but it is prompting me to serverB as if I ssh to it to run command:

```
ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No -i "Key.pem" user@BserverIP " sudo su -;su - grid;crsctl stop has;su -;shutdown now"
```

then I need it to exit to run rest of my script that I am running on serverA.

I looked on many links but nothing worked. Will you help?

---

Edit:

Partial of my answer here: [Commands will not pass to CLI after logging into new user with sudo su - user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273708/commands-will-not-pass-to-cli-after-logging-into-new-user-with-sudo-su-user)

When I run:

```
ssh -qt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No -i "Key.pem" user@serverB "whoami; sudo -u userB whoami"
```

output is:  user and userB, if I add another command it is pulling it from user not userB

```
ssh -qt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No -i "Key.pem" user@serverB "whoami; sudo -u userB ls"
```

ls is getting output from user not userB.

WHat is the correct way to run?

```
su - grid ; crsctl stop has
```

from the same command.

Comment: Everything after `;` will be executed after `sudo su -` exits. It's not input to the `sudo su -` command.

Comment: I am sorry what do you mean? so it can't be done?

Comment: I closed it as a duplicate of a question that shows how to do things like this.

Comment: in my case if I run: ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No -i "Key.pem" user@BserverIP " sudo u ;su - grid;crsctl stop has;su -;shutdown now". should work correct, I will try it and let you know.. thank you

Comment: That looks like what you wrote in the question, you didn't try to use the solutions in the linked question.

Comment: I will try it today when I get back to my server: Thank you for your prompt answer.

Comment: Thank you Barmar to your patience: when I run :

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments. Edit the question.

Comment: ok I updated my question

Comment: How can you tell which user is executing `ls`?

Comment: basically I was testing to make sure I can run command on the grid user witch is Oracle.so I need to run command as userB : 
Manually I do :
sudo su - 
su - grid
crsctl stop has
then exit the grid user

Comment: The `whoami` test shows you that it's running as `userB`. There's no reason why `ls` would be any different.

Comment: I added more details in the main question to avoid writing command in comment

Comment: `su - grid -c "crsctl stop has"`

Comment: Just like you would if you were running it by hand.

Comment: have you read the man page for `su` to see how to tell it to run a command?

Comment: Yes I think I confused myself, so if I need to run more command, just include them in "" or should I separate them in ;

Comment: You can put any shell command line inside the `-c` argument. It can contain multiple commands separated by `;`

Comment: `su - username -c "command1; command2; ..."`

Comment: Note that nesting quoted strings inside ssh and sudo can be tricky. It would probably be easier if you put a script on the remove machine that does everything, and then execute the script using `ssh`.

Comment: Thank you so much , I really appreciate you.